# How to format a phone numbers with libphonenumber in International format.

Tags: c#-4.0, libphonenumber

In the [documentation](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) provided by libphonenumber on Github, there is a [demo](https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html), which converts any provided number into International Format, e.g `+4915213116250` is converted into `+49 1521 3116250`

I want to use the same functionality in C#.

In the documentation of libphone, there is need to parse the number and provide the countries/regions. But the demo works without providing the region/country. Can some body let me know how it is done?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
var phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
var numberProto = phoneUtil.Parse("1234567890", "IT");
var formattedPhone = phoneUtil.Format(numberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
```

This will give you `"+39 123 456 7890"`

Comment: How to validate phone number? I don't know how to set PhoneNumber - it has a lot of params, but mostly they are readonly.

Comment: @FrenkyB use phoneUtil.Parse and then phoneUtil.IsValidNumber

Answer (score 2):

@danyolgiax almost had it. Here's what you do:

```
var phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
var numberProto = phoneUtil.Parse("+4915213116250", "ZZ"); //why ZZ means international i don't know
var formattedPhone = phoneUtil.Format(numberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
```

Remember to use `phoneUtil.IsValidNumber` if you aren't certain that the phone number is valid. Also be aware that `phoneUtil.Parse` may throw.

Comment: ZZ dont work  i get PhoneNumbers.NumberParseException: 'Missing or invalid default region.'