# Verify phone number using PhoneNumbers.dll with C#, Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, phonenumberutils

I am trying to verify phone number using PhoneNumbers.dll(File version 8.9.0.0) for twillio SMS API with C# (Visual studio 2010)

Lines of Code used in application:

```
private static PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
private static List<string> supportedRegions = phoneUtil.GetSupportedRegions().ToList<string>();
```

After application build, facing below error

> The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly  'netstandard,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t01PQ.png)

In case same dll used in .Net 2015 no error results with build successed.
Please suggest to over come system.object error in .net 2010

Comment: either add netstandard 2 or restore you nugets

Comment: Thanks @Michael Randall, please share me the link for net standard 2 supported for visual studio 2010.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: yes, actually netstandard2 will not support for visual studio 2010 (I tried to by downloading from Microsoft link.)

Comment: I need to use libphonenumber dll to verify phone number using visual studio 2010 , please suggest to implement in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why .net standard is not working for you

however if you really need to you can go to an early version of libphonenumber-csharp

https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/7.7.4

Comment: please share me the link to download net standard 2 supported for visual studio 2010

Comment: @Pavankumar the nuget package i linked you to, that particular version 7.7.4 doesn't require .net standard, you don't need it with that version

Comment: Thank you for the responses and suggestions

 I have used phonenumbers.dll version 3.7.1.306 and used below link to for my understanding 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611446/how-to-format-a-phone-numbers-with-libphonenumber-in-international-format

var phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
var numberProto = phoneUtil.Parse("1234567890", "IT");
var formattedPhone = phoneUtil.Format(numberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);

Comment: @Pavankumar you shouldn't need to go back to version 3. 7.7.4 seems like it would work, anyway im glad you got it working